# Get value of pivot table

Tags: php, laravel

I have the following setup:

```
|locations|products|reps|

|id,name  |id,name |id,name,phone,etc|
```

I have also created this pivot table (location_products_rep):

```
|location_id|products_id|rep_id|
```

Calling the code below returns the values in the pivot table

```
foreach ($reps->repNames as $rep)
    {
        echo $rep->pivot->rep_id;
        echo $rep->pivot->product_id;
        echo $rep->pivot->location_id;
    }
```

Result: 1 1 1 , which is correct. But what I need is the product name, rep name and location name.

How would i get it to read: Result: Frank Bananas China

OR

Am I better off to make a model for the pivot tabel and pull relations through there like a normal model would?

**UPDATE**

I ended up just making a model for the pivot table and pulling relations on that using

```
RepFinderPivot::with('repNames', 'repProducts', 'repLocation')
```

My original question stands but this works for now.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that extending the belongsToMany relationships on your models and chaining into `->using(RelatedModel)` would be better for you in this case. You wouldn't have to deal with an intermediate table as a result.

```
class Use extends Pivot
{
    /**
     * The users that belong to the role.
     */
    public function reps()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User')->using('App\Product');
    }
}
```

Not sure if this would work or not since Product only has the rep_id.

Comment: i need the pivot table though don't i?. Example, one rep may be in china for product "a" but doesn't sell product "b" in china but another rep in china sells product "b" but not "a".   I thought things like this needed a  pivot table.

Comment: Yeah I think you're right actually, I've been reading more of the docs since I posted that and it seems like that's the case. However I still think chaining through the belongsToMany() can get you where you need.